# Matching text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkbox that are used to select options.  These options, once clicked make a database call to see if there are options that are listed for the clicked option.

What it returns is the text name of those listed options.  I am trying to than check my list of checkable options with the list that was returned.  For each individual option I check the name with the names returned to know if there is a match.

My issue is using:

```
if($(this).parent().text() == restrictionArray[i])
```

Does not seem to be a totally accurate way of checking if the text of that option `$(this).parent().text()` contains the same text as the returned: `restrictionArray[i]`.

What I have come across is that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not even if they both contain the same text.

Heres exactly what I am doing:

```
// CREATE NEEDED ARRAY FROM SINGLE STRING
var restrictionArray = data["data_retrieved"].split(',');
// CREATE LOOP TO LOOP THROUGH DATA TO MAKE NEEDED RESTRICTIONS
for(var i = 0; i < restrictionArray.length; i++)
{
// RUN THROUGH EVERY OPTION
    $(".option_checkbox").each(function() {
    // IF OPTION CONTAINS SELECTED RESTRICTION
 if($(this).parent().text() == restrictionArray[i])
     {
      // CHANGE OPTION'S CSS
      $(this).parent().css('color', 'lightgray');
      $(this).parent().css('pointer-events', 'none');// <!-- THIS IS KEY TO STOP CLICk   
     }
    }); 
}
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: "*What I have come across is that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not even if they both contain the same text.*". Sounds like a white spacing issue. Code never reacts one way and then randomly stops working. There's always a reason and a change.

Comment: Try trim both text text and then compare

Comment: what is the parent of .option_checkbox ? and do RESTRICTIONS values match text with upper/lower case letters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I have come across is that sometimes it works and sometimes it
>   does not even if they both contain the same text.

I presume white space is your issue, as noted in comments.

I would suggest you to `trim` it in `if` condition.

```
if($(this).parent().text().trim() == restrictionArray[i])
```